# Camel Kafka serialization error

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

I am new to camel and kafka. 
I am using Camel 2.18.2 with Kafka 0.10.1.1

I am getting this error and don't understand why:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer

I have the following route:

```
from("direct://toEnrichEmail") 
.routeId(routeId).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Map.class) 
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Sending to Kafka: ${body}") 
.to("kafka:localhost:9092?topic=enrich-email&requestRequiredAcks=-1");
```

The code that actually sends to the route:

```
ProducerTemplate template = kafkaProducerFactory.getProducerTemplate(); 
            logger.debug("Sending message type: {}, to uri: {}, route: {}", wimsConfiguration.getMessageType(), 
                            wimsConfiguration.getDirectUri(), wimsConfiguration.getRouteName()); 
            Map<String,Object>headers = new HashMap<>(); // added because the examples do 
            headers.put(KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY, 0); 
            headers.put(KafkaConstants.KEY, "1"); 
            template.sendBodyAndHeaders(wimsConfiguration.getDirectUri(), wimsConfiguration.getWimsMessage(), headers);
```

The log message in the route shows that the message is a proper JSON string, the default serializer is string, So why is it complaining that it cannot serialize?

I looked through the camel kafka component test cases and this looks like it should work

Here is a sample of the output from Camel/kafka logs:

> 16:32:20,967 INFO  [toEnrichEmail] (default task-12) Sending to Kafka: {"messageType":"orderCreate","regionCode":"IN","regionLanguage":["en"],"orderHeader":{"order":"3001357952","salesOrg":"2123","soldTo":"2035266752","currency":"INR","documentType":"TA","validFrom":null,"validTo":null,"contactName":"UI IN","contactPhone":"","contactEmail":"fu.bar@baz.com"},"shipTo":{"customerNumber":"2035266752","companyName":"INTERNET PRICE FOR EOU","cityName":"Bangalore","district":"","postalCode":"","streetName":"","houseNumber":"","building":"","floor":"","roomNumber":"","countryName":"India","regionName":"Karnataka"},"billTo":{"customerNumber":"2035266752","companyName":"INTERNET PRICE FOR EOU","cityName":"Indi","district":"","postalCode":"","streetName":"","houseNumber":"","building":"","floor":"","roomNumber":"","countryName":"India","regionName":"Karnataka"},"paymentInfo":{"paymentMethod":"PO","purchaseOrder":"1234567","requisitionNumber":"","creditCardNumber":"","paymentterms":"","incoterms":""},"orderSummary":{"orderSubtotal":"6479.52","discounts":"0","shippingTransportation":"0","salesTax":"1187.92","dutyTotal":"1712.56","orderTotal":"9380"},"orderItems":[{"quoteNumber":null,"quoteItemNumber":"000010","totalReservedQunatity":null,"remainingReservedQuantity":null,"lineItemNo":"000010","itemCategory":"TAN","qty":"1","material":"T6066-1KG","product":"T6066","brandId":"SIGMA","description":"TRIZMA(R) BASE, BIOPERFORMANCE CERTIF&","yourRef":"","yourPrice":"8192.08","listPrice":"8192.08"}]}
>         16:32:21,008 ERROR [org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-12) Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-STLDEEPX06-sial-com-49604-1486506685312-1-1 on ExchangeId: ID-STLDEEPX06-sial-com-49604-1486506685312-1-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
>
> Blockquote

### Message History

RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[toEnrichEmail     ] [toEnrichEmail     ] [direct://toEnrichEmail                                                        ] [        57]
[toEnrichEmail     ] [marshal1          ] [marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonDataFormat@142a2fec]            ] [        10]
[toEnrichEmail     ] [log4              ] [log                                                                           ] [        15]
[toEnrichEmail     ] [to3               ] [kafka:localhost:9092?topic=enrich-email&requestRequiredAcks=-1                ] [        25]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer

16:32:21,011 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) 2017-02-07T16:32:21,010 INFO  com.sial.notifications.common.rest.NotificationExceptionResponseMapper - Mapping Exception org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-STLDEEPX06-sial-com-49604-1486506685312-1-2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) 2017-02-07T16:32:21,014 ERROR com.sial.notifications.common.rest.NotificationExceptionResponseMapper - Mapped exception org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-STLDEEPX06-sial-com-49604-1486506685312-1-2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-STLDEEPX06-sial-com-49604-1486506685312-1-2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12)   at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1779) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12)   at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:677) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12)   at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12)   at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12)   at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:259) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12)   at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:253) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
16:32:21,021 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12)   at com.sial.notifications.messages.rest.NotificationMessageServiceImpl.submitMessageToRoute(NotificationMessageServiceImpl.java:66) ~[classes:?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` after marshaling the class to JSON. That shouldn't be necessary, but doing this made Kafka happy.

Answer (score 2):

add `serializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer` to the producer config

Or

add `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` after marshaling the object to JSON as you said

I would prefer the former one as it's one less operation.

Comment: instead of String i add my Custom class and it works ,thanks